# Duvida cirar caixa de dialogo no android studio

Tags: android

Boa tarde!
Estou com uma duvida no android onde estou criando um app para avaliar  o humor do usuario .
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu crie o código de tal forma que so aceite uma opção por dia
So que agora preciso incluir uma janela informando que ele ja realizou o teste se o mesmo já tenha feito e preciso que apos ele ter respondido abra uma caixa de dialogo para incluir informações pessoais tipo nome telefone etc..
Segue abaixo o código feito ate o momento:

```
public class ActPrincipal extends Activity {
    private ImageButton ibMuitoSatisfeito, ibSatisfeito, ibNeutro, ibInsatisfeito, ibMuitoInsatisfeito;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_principal);

        ibMuitoSatisfeito = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibMuitoInsatisfeito);
        ibSatisfeito = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibSatisfeito);
        ibNeutro = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibNeutro);
        ibInsatisfeito = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibInsatisfeito);
        ibMuitoInsatisfeito = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibMuitoInsatisfeito);

        ibMuitoSatisfeito.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                salvarAvaliacao(1);
                return true;
            }
        }
        );
        ibSatisfeito.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {               
                salvarAvaliacao(2);
                return true;
              }
          }
        ); ibNeutro.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                salvarAvaliacao(3);
                 return true;
             }
         }
        );
        ibMuitoInsatisfeito.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                salvarAvaliacao(5);
                return true;
            }
        }
        );
    }

    public void salvarAvaliacao(int nro) {
        Controlador controlador = new Controlador(getBaseContext());
        Avaliacao avaliacao = new Avaliacao();
        avaliacao.setDataAvaliacao(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date()));
        avaliacao.setHorario(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
        avaliacao.setAvaliacao(nro);
        avaliacao.setEnviado(0);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 12);
        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            Location localizacao = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

            if (localizacao != null && ((new Date()).getTime() - localizacao.getTime()) / 1000 < 3600) {
                avaliacao.setLatitude(localizacao.getLatitude());
                avaliacao.setLongitude(localizacao.getLongitude());
            }
        }
        controlador.inserir(avaliacao);
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.msg_agradecimento), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void btAbrirActAvaliacao(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActAvaliacao.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que a lógica pode ser melhorada e muito. Como analisei parte do seu código e percebi que está aprendendo Android, vou te sugerir seguir esse roteiro (não vou te propor técnicas mais apuradas):

2 Activities:

TesteHumor (que aparece as opções para votar).
DadosPessoais (com um layout com nome, telefone e email).

A activity principal seria TesteHumor. É a MAIN activity da aplicação. Quando o usuário acessa para votar, você verifica se já votou hoje (por banco SQLite, SharedPreferences... o meio não importa). Se já votou, você pode ter nessa activity um layout apenas com textview informando que ele já votou. Se não votou, carrega o layout de votação layouts no mesmo XML. Um você exibe (setVisibility) e o outro você oculta). Dentro do mesmo XML de layout você pode trabalhar exibindo um e ocultando o outro (mas não é sempre que isso é recomendado). Após ele ter votado (se for a primeira vez, você carrega a activity DadosPessoais).

Sempre procure revisar sua pergunta afim de tornar clara e concisa.  Perguntas muito genéricas ou pedindo códigos completos (soluções para o seu problema) podem prejudicar sua reputação. Sempre procure ser específico e estudar antes de perguntar, pois alguém já deu um "-1" na sua dúvida.

Um abraço e espero ter ajudado.